# How do I whitelist a Google Mail address while still blocking a key spam-word?

Tags: gmail-filters

I have a fairly substantial Google Mail filter list, probably around sixty entries in total, the vast majority of which block mail using the action "Mark as read, Delete it."

Three of these rules block any inbound email containing the word "survey" in the sender address, subject, or body of the message respectively. None of the people I do business with use this word in the context of day-to-day conversation so it rarely triggers a false positive, and it blocks the constant barrage of surveys that companies want me to fill out.

But recently, I activated email notifications from Amazon's "hub" (thehub@amazon.com) to notify me when I have a package waiting and as luck would have it, their notification template actually *does* contain the word "survey." I want to see these messages in my inbox so I whitelisted sender thehub@amazon.com using the action "Never send it to Spam, Mark it as important." What's the proper way to ensure that my whitelist rule takes precedence over the survey-blocking rule, given that all notifications from thehub@amazon.com will contain the word "survey?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your "survey" filter to disregard that email address: `from:(-thehub@amazon.com) survey`